# How do I fire a mouse click on a C# MenuStrip when a form become activated/focused?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, menustrip, onmouseclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Click lost on focusing form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958756/click-lost-on-focusing-form)

If a form with a `MenuStrip` is not the window that has focus and you click on the `MenuStrip`, it uses that first click to make the window active, and then you have to click the `MenuStrip` *again* to get the menu to drop down. Buttons work differently. If a form with a button is not active/does not have focus and you click that button, it will register as a button click on that first click, as well as simultaneously making that form active/focused. I really need that menu on the `MenuStrip` to drop down on that first click, even if the form isn't active.

I tried using the `OnMouseClick(...)` method to fire a simulated mouse click when the form Enter and/or Activate events are triggered but that doesn't work. The Enter and Activate events are triggered on Mouse Down, so by putting an `OnMouseClick(...)` call in the Enter or Activate event handler, it's trying to fire a SECOND mouse click before the first mouse click has been released.

I somehow need the `OnMouseClick(...)` to occur after the Activate event occurs and then after `MouseUp` occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Use this MenuStrip derivate as replacement:

```
public class ActivatingMenuStrip : MenuStrip
{
    public ActivatingMenuStrip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x21;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
        {
            this.Parent.Focus();
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    }

}
```